# Proving a space is not Banach in $\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am aiming to prove that with the norm on $\ell^{1}$ given by $\left\|\left(a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots\right)\right\|=\sup \left\{\left|a_{n}\right|: n \geq 1\right\}$, $\left(\ell^{1},\|\cdot\|\right)$ is not a Banach space.

So I need to prove that every Cauchy sequence in $\left(\ell^{1},\|\cdot\|\right)$ converges to some element of $\left(\ell^{1},\|\cdot\|\right)$.

I tried by starting with a sequence $(x^{(n)})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x^{n}=(0,0,\dots,1/n,0,0,\dots)$ where the value $1/n$ is the $n$-th element. But, i didn't manage to get anywhere with this. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: One way to do this is to notice that $\ell^1$ with the infinity norm is a dense proper subspace of the Banach space $c_0$ (of sequences that converge to $0$) with the infinity norm and so cannot be complete.

Comment: @Bcpicao it comes from exercise 6C Q7 in Sheldon Axler's Measure, Integration & Real Analysis (fantastic book btw!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x^n=(1,1/2,\ldots,1/n,0,\ldots)$.

FIRST: This sequence is $\|\cdot\|$-Cauchy.
Indeed, assuming $n>k$, we have that
$$\|x^n-x^k\|=\|(0,\ldots,0,1/(k+1),\ldots,1/n,0,\ldots)\|=$$ $$=\sup\{1/j,\ k+1\le j\le n\}=\frac{1}{k+1}\to0\ (k\to\infty).
$$

SECOND: We can prove that $x^n\overset{\|\cdot\|}{\longrightarrow} x:=(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots)$.
Indeed $\|x^n-x\|=\|(0,\ldots,0,1/(n+1),1/(n+2),\ldots)\| =\sup_{j>n}\frac{1}{j}=\frac{1}{n+1}\to0\ (n\to\infty)$.

THIRD It is clear that $x^n\in\ell^1$ but $x\notin\ell^1$.

So you have a $\|\cdot\|$-Cauchy sequence $(x^n)_n\subset\ell^1$ that is $\|\cdot\|$-convergent to something not belonging to $\ell^1$.

Comment: I don't know if you can elucidate me on this, but is the following implication true? If $N_1$ is a norm finer than $N_2$ then $(X,N_1)$ is complete implies $(X,N_2)$ complete?

Comment: Sotty, not sure about that.

Comment: I'm asking this because, in your example, you took a sequence $(x^k)_k$ that is not Cauchy in $(l_1,||.||_1)$ either. My question is basically, is there an example of a sequence that is Cauchy w respect to the 1-norm and not to the sup norm? There shouldn't be, right?